# Getting continuous values from a function

Tags: python

I currently have a school task with micro:bit and more specifically bit:bots. I am trying to make a code where the robot will stop and reverse when it is 5cm or closer to a wall. My problem is that my code is only getting the distance from the sonar (HC-SR04) every time the code executes, and not during the code when it really needs to check the distance.

I have tried setting different parts of the sonar code into a while loop without any success (may have just set the wrong parts into the loop). I have also tried different methods of writing the main code where it tells the robot what functions to follow.

```py
from microbit import *
import neopixel
import time
from utime import ticks_us, sleep_us

np = neopixel.NeoPixel(pin13, 12) 
headlight = (150,150,100)
rearlight = (180,0,0)
reversinglight = (50,50,50)
indicator = (255,80,0)

def sonar():
    pin15.write_digital(1)
    sleep_us(10) 
    pin15.write_digital(0)
    pin15.set_pull(SONAR.NO_PULL)
    while pin15.read_digital() == 0:
        pass 
    start = ticks_us() 
    while pin15.read_digital() == 1:
        pass 
    end = ticks_us()
    echo = end-start 
    distance = int(0.01715 * echo)
    return distance 

def forover():
    pin1.write_analog(500)
    pin12.write_digital(0)
    pin0.write_analog(500)
    pin8.write_digital(0)

    np[9]  = headlight
    np[3]  = headlight
    np[5]  = headlight
    np[4]  = headlight
    np[10]  = headlight
    np[11]  = headlight
    np.show() 

    while True: 
        np[0]  = indicator
        np[1]  = indicator
        np[6]  = indicator
        np[7]  = indicator 
        np.show() 
        sleep(600)
        np[0]  = (0,0,0)
        np[1]  = (0,0,0)
        np[6]  = (0,0,0)
        np[7]  = (0,0,0)
        np.show() 
        sleep(600)

def reverse(): 
    pin1.write_analog(200) 
    pin12.write_digital(1) 
    pin0.write_analog(200) 
    pin8.write_digital(1) 

    np[5]  = rearlight
    np[4]  = rearlight
    np[11]  = rearlight
    np[10]  = rearlight
    np[9]  = reversinglight
    np[8]  = reversinglight
    np[3]  = reversinglight
    np[2]  = reversinglight
    np.show()

    while True:
        pin14.write_digital(1)
        np[0]  = indicator
        np[1]  = indicator
        np[6]  = indicator
        np[7]  = indicator
        np.show()
        sleep(600)
        np[0]  = (0,0,0)
        np[1]  = (0,0,0)
        np[6]  = (0,0,0)
        np[7]  = (0,0,0)
        np.show()
        pin14.write_digital(0) 
        sleep(600)

while True:
    if sonar() <= 5:
        reverse()
    else:
        forover()
```

I am very new to python so i'll take any critism as long as it helps me learn! Hopefully someone is able to help me :)

Comment: Once the code executes, it only calls reverse or forover once. That's because the two functions have a while True and the execution gets stuck there.

Comment: I think the previous comment is right.  Maybe if you change the while True in those two functions to while sonar() <=5 it will do what you want.

Comment: The robot still just drives forwards without any regards to distance. It still only checks the distance when the code is first executed.